# UpdateView does not show existing data when using filter

Tags: python, django

I am quite new with Django and I need help.

My problem is quite similar what Mike had in his case:
[UpdateView not populating form with existing data](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54165717/updateview-not-populating-form-with-existing-data), but I have not found solution yet.

My goal is to view owner dropdown selection list only those users who are members of the organization.

models.py

```
# organizations.models.py
...
from accounts.models import User
from core.models import TimeStampModel
...

class Organization(TimeStampModel, models.Model):
    id = models.UUIDField(primary_key=True, default=uuid.uuid4, editable=False)

    name = models.CharField(
        verbose_name=_('Name'),
        max_length=255,
        unique=True
    )

    code = models.CharField(
        verbose_name=_('Code'),
        max_length=255,
        null=True,
        blank=True
    )

    owner = models.ForeignKey(
        User,
        on_delete=models.PROTECT,
        verbose_name=_('Owner'),
        related_name='owner',
        help_text=_('Organization Owner and Contact Person'),
    )

    slug = models.SlugField(verbose_name=_('Organization key'), unique=True)

    ...

    class Meta:
        verbose_name = _('Organization')
        verbose_name_plural = _('Organization')
        ordering = ['name', 'code']

    def __str__(self):
        return f'{self.name}, {self.code}'

    # Create automatically slug value from organization name field.
    # In case similar is exist then add extra count digit end of slug.
    def _get_unique_slug(self):
        slug = slugify(self.name)
        unique_slug = slug
        num = 1
        while Organization.objects.filter(slug=unique_slug).exists():
            unique_slug = '{}-{}'.format(slug, num)
            num += 1
        return unique_slug

    def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
        if not self.slug:
            self.slug = self._get_unique_slug()

        self.next_update = timezone.now() + relativedelta(
            months=self.update_interval)
        super(Organization, self).save(*args, **kwargs)


    def get_absolute_url(self):
        kwargs = {
            'slug': self.slug
        }
        return reverse('organization_main_page', kwargs=kwargs)


class OrganizationMembers(models.Model):
    id = models.UUIDField(primary_key=True, default=uuid.uuid4, editable=False)

    organization = models.ForeignKey(
        Organization,
        on_delete=models.CASCADE,
        verbose_name=_('Organization')
    )

    member = models.ForeignKey(
        User,
        on_delete=models.CASCADE,
        verbose_name=_('Member'),
        null=True,
        blank=True
    )

    organization_admin = models.BooleanField(
        verbose_name=_('Organization admin'),
        default=False
    )

    class Meta:
        verbose_name = _('Organization: Member')
        verbose_name_plural = _('Organization: Members')
        ordering = ['organization', 'member']
        unique_together = ('organization', 'member')

    def __str__(self):
        return f'{self.member}'

    def get_absolute_url(self):
        kwargs = {
            'slug': self.slug
        }
        return reverse('organization_detail', kwargs=kwargs)
```

forms.py

```
# organizations.forms.py
....
from accounts.models import User
from .models import Organization, OrganizationMembers
...

class OrganizationUpdateForm(forms.ModelForm):

    class Meta:
        model = Organization
        fields = '__all__'
        exclude = ('date_created', 'created_by', 'created_by_id',
                   'last_updated', 'last_updated_by', 'last_updated_by_id',
                   'next_update', 'slug')


    # Restrict user selection lists to view only members of the organization
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        inst = kwargs.get('instance', None)

        super(OrganizationUpdateForm, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)

        self.fields['owner'].queryset = OrganizationMembers.objects.\    # <--- !!!
             filter(organization_id=inst.id)
```

In the forms.py, if I comment out self.field['owner]... line, then owner field will show saved value from database, but then I can see all users in the dropdown list. When queryset is enabled then selection list show correct users, but saved value is not visible.

views.py

```
# organizations.views.py

from .forms import OrganizationUpdateForm

from accounts.models import User
from .models import Organization, OrganizationMembers


class OrganizationUpdateView(LoginRequiredMixin, UpdateView):
    model = Organization
    form_class = OrganizationUpdateForm
    template_name = 'organizations/organization_update.html'
    success_url = reverse_lazy('organizations')

    # Save data and set current user to last updated by fields
    def form_valid(self, form):
        object = form.save(commit=False)
        object.last_updated_by = self.request.user.get_full_name()
        object.last_updated_by_id = self.request.user

        return super(OrganizationUpdateView, self).form_valid(form)

    def get_queryset(self):
        criteria1 = Q(owner=self.request.user)
        criteria2 = Q(organizationmembers__member=self.request.user)
        criteria3 = Q(organizationmembers__organization_admin=1)
        org_list = Organization.objects.\
            filter(criteria1 | (criteria2 & criteria3)).distinct()

        if org_list.count() != 0:
            return org_list
        else:
            raise Http404('You don\'t have permissions!')
```

In Mikes case Chiheb has commented that "*With UpdateView it's a little bit tricky. So, in order to initialize your form's data, you need to do it in the view itself not in the form.*"

What is the reason that cannot add filter to UpdateView?

Please can someone help me to solve my problem. Thanks.

**UPDATE**

[Not filtered. Value from database is visible](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lCMa5.png)

[Not filtered. Dropdown list show all users in the system](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yW7Tq.png)

[Filter enabled. Value is not visible](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4VxJd.png)

[Filter enabled. Dropdown list show correct valeus](https://i.stack.imgur.com/S6aeS.png)

Comment: What do you mean by "saved data is not visible"?

Comment: When I create new organization owner will be set current user and user cannot change it in creationview. In UpdateView user can change owner to be some one else. When I have disabled filtter queryset in modelform and I open organization update view I can see who is the owner (value comes from database). But when I enabled filtter queryset, owner field is empty and when I open dropdown I can see that user is on the list.

Comment: I added screenshots

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is that `owner` in your models is a FK to `User` model, but you are filtering queryset in form by `OrganizationMembers`. Make it the same and the problem should be gone.

Comment: Thanks Andrey. You are right, I didn't realise that I had wrong model in owner field. Now it works fine.